# Remove lines separating cells in seaborn heatmap when saved as pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I would like to remove the lines that separate the cells in a saved pdf. I tried setting the linewidth=0.0, but the lines are still showing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(data,linewidths=0.0)
fig.savefig('stackoverflow_lines.pdf')
```

The image is a screen capture of the resulting pdf.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is an issue only when saving to PDF files, if you use something like a PNG then it will work fine. A Github Issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/373) with the developers.

In the meantime, the developer mwaskom has found a fix where you can add `rasterized=True` to the `seaborn.heatmap` function which fixes the issue. Your code then becomes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(data,linewidths=0.0, rasterized=True)
fig.savefig('stackoverflow_lines.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed by the developer-- you can now save as PDF without any gridlines showing by excluding the 'linewidths' value. Note I also added 'square=True' to give square-shaped output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(data, square=True)
fig.savefig('stackoverflow_lines.pdf',format='pdf')
```

[image: Screen Capture of Resulting PDF]

Comment: When has this been fixed? For my v0.12.2 your code produces tiny white lines between the squares.

Comment: I get the posted results with seaborn v0.12.2 and matplotlib v3.7.1. I am running python 3.10.12 in Spyder on Windows. Hope that helps!